# Why does my node's style only decrease and not increase?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on a website, and I'm trying to programmatically fade an object in and out.
However when i run my loop it only subtracts the opacity from the object, when I try to add to the opacity it just stays at 0.01 for the entire 100 loops, but when it runs 100-199 it subtracts 0.01 every time.
I'm confused why its doing such...

```
function searched() {
    var count = 0;
    if (srched) {
        return
    } else {

        let runloop = setInterval(function () {
            if (count <= 99) {
                document.getElementById("done").style.opacity += 0.01;
            } else if (count > 99 && count <= 199) {
                document.getElementById("done").style.opacity -= 0.01;
            } else {
                clearInterval(this)
                srched = false;
            }
            count += 1;
        }, 40)

    }

}
```

The html code is:

```
<p id = "done" style="opacity: 0; color: #1a5b02;">
```

There's no problem with the loop, just adding to the opacity.

Comment: <p id = "done" style="opacity: 0; color: #1a5b02;">

Comment: Answer to the problem is below, but the real solution is to use a CSS animation. That way you wouldn't have to resort to JS.

Comment: eh I like using javascript personally I'm trying to improve at it since I just started using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `+=` can also mean concatenation, so the opacity property gets a value of `'0' + '0.01' = '00.01'` for a value the first time in the loop, which is corrected to 0.01, but then you get `'0.010.01'` in the next iteration, which is an error.

`-=` does not have the problem - it cannot be a string operation, so it just does the subtraction.

Solution: make sure not to do concatenation by mistake. I think the shortest solution is to write `...opacity -= -0.01;` but I'm curious if there are any shorter ones ;)

Comment: wow didn't even think about that lol flew right past my head how css takes it as a string. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: I couldn't see from the source either what was going wrong, so I had to look in the error console. Those error messages are there for a reason!

Comment: ya it wasn't showing me anything in the error console was the weird part so I kept just trying different solutions but couldn't quite get it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Number()` to add/subtract your opacity, otherwise it is treating as string and hence your effect is not working

```js
var srched=false;
function searched() {
    var count = 0,done=document.getElementById("done");
    if (srched) {
        return
    } else {

        let runloop = setInterval(function () {
            if (count <= 99) {
                done.style.opacity = Number(done.style.opacity)+0.01;
            } else if (count > 99 && count <= 199) {
                done.style.opacity = Number(done.style.opacity)-0.01;
            } else {
                clearInterval(this)
                srched = false;
            }
            count += 1;
        }, 40)

    }

}
searched();
```

```html
<p id="done">Lorem ipsum doner inut</p>
```

Comment: I had already tried that but ya that would've worked to it was the concatenation trying to save time and being lazy that got me lol